# align an image and some text on the same line without using div width?

Tags: css, image, html, alignment

Ok so I'm trying to align an image(which is contained in a div) and some text(also contained in a div) on the same line, without setting width for the text, how can i do it? This is what I have so far.

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="image" style="float:left;">
        <img src="tree.png"  align="left"/>
    </div>

    <div id="texts" style="float:left;"> 
        A very long text(about 300 words) 
    </div>

</div>
```

When the text is short, the image and text can be fit into the same line, but my text is pretty long, and it automatically jumps on another line below the image.

Basically, now it's this: http://puu.sh/MPw2
I want to make this: http://puu.sh/MPvr

I'm been trying to solve this problem for like 3 hours I'm so noob please help? :S

Comment: What you're trying to do is not clear to me. What I think you should try is setting a new style to both your divs. Try: "display: inline;". And you're using inline styles just to ask your question or you're doing it also in your project? Also, I'm not quite sure if you really want to use an "id" instead of a "class" for "image" and "texts".

Comment: Basically, now it's this: http://puu.sh/MPw2 I want to make this: http://puu.sh/MPvr

Comment: Ok, so you have to add a width to your #image, and a width to your #texts... you can try adding to each one of them something like: "width: 30%;", just an example. Since you don't have a width to your divs and they are "block" elements, each one is using 100% of existing width, making them sit one below the other, even if you're "floating" them.

Comment: yea I tried with width it works, but how can i make it work without using width? :S cuz I'm trying to make it work on iPhone, and once I set some width, on iphone(cuz the screen is slim) will not see the entire text

Comment: You have fixed widths on iphone, so you can set fixed widths there too. Imagine the iphone has a width of 960x640px. You can set your #container to width: 640px; your #image to width: 300px; and your #texts to width: 300px; and this will work.

Answer (score 32):

Floating will result in wrapping if space is not available.

You can use `display:inline` and `white-space:nowrap` to achieve this. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FQqWz/)

```
<div id="container" style="white-space:nowrap">

    <div id="image" style="display:inline;">
        <img src="tree.png"/>
    </div>

    <div id="texts" style="display:inline; white-space:nowrap;"> 
        A very long text(about 300 words) 
    </div>

</div>​
```

Comment: @user1561559. [It is working for me](http://jsfiddle.net/FQqWz/) in IE9, FF14, Safari 5.1.1, Chrome 20. Where is it not working for you?

Comment: well when the text is very long, like 300 words or something, the text will exceed the screen width, then i have to scroll horizontally to see the entire text

Comment: Still works great in 2018; should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 14):

Try

```
<img src="assets/img/logo.png" align="left" />
Text Goes here
```

Simple HTML Attribute:

```
align="left"
```

Other values for attribute:

- bottom
- left
- middle
- right
- top

Comment: this is deprecated

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is over 6 years old, but still, I would like to share my method using tables and this won't require any CSS.

```
<table><tr><td><img src="loading.gif"></td><td> Loading...</td></tr></table>
```

Cheers!
Happy Coding

Comment: We shouldn't be using tables in 2018 for showing anything other than tabular data!

Answer (score 4):

To get the desired effect, you should place the image tag inside the same div as your text.  Then set the `float: left` attribute on the image.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

I was working on a different project when I saw this question, this is the solution I used and it seems to work.

```
#[image id] , p {
        vertical-align: middle;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

if it doesn't, just try :

```
float:right;

float:left;
```

or 
`display: inline` instead of `inline-block`

This worked for me, hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

Method1:

Inline elements do not use any width or height you specify.
To avoid two div and use like this:

```
 <div id="container">
<img src="tree.png"  align="left"/>
<h1> A very long text(about 300 words) </h1>
</div>
    <style>
            img {
                display: inline;
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
            }
            h1 {
                display: inline;
            }
        </style>
```

Method2:

Change your CSS as follows

```
.container div {
    display: inline-block;
    }
```

Method3:

It is the simple method set width
Try the following css:

```
.container div {
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
width:90%;
margin-bottom:20px;
margin-top:20px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
.image {
width:70%;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
}
.texts { 
height: auto;
width: 30%;
display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<p>Click on <img src="/storage/help/button2.1.png" width="auto" 
height="28"align="middle"/> button will show a page as bellow</p>
```

It works for me

Comment: width, height and align parameters are obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

From [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48346509/12818901) :

```
<table>
<tr style="background-color:white">
    <th><b>To solve your doubts &ensp; &nbsp;</b></th>
    <th><img src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png" style="width:150px" style="display:inline-block; "/></th><th style="float:right"></th>
    <th><b>&ensp; has the requisite clout.</b></th>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Demo:**
[image]

:D A little cheesy but, I thought, why not.

Answer (score 0):

I built on the last answer and used `display:table` for an outer div, and `display:table-cell` for inner divs.

This was the only thing that worked for me using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the img css to be `display:inline` or `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

U wrote an unnecessary div, just leave it like this

```html
<div id="texts" style="white-space:nowrap;">
     <img src="tree.png"  align="left"/>
     A very long text(about 300 words) 
</div>
```

What u are looking for is white-space:nowrap; this code will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="container" style="display: flex;">

<div id="image" style="float:left; margin-top: 10px">
    <img src="tree.png"  align="left"/>
</div>

<div id="texts" style="float:left;"> 
    A very long text(about 300 words) 
</div>
```

use display flex and give margin-top(10 is approximate), please remove the float and give width to both div.