# How can I have an image on the same line as text in html

Tags: html

I am in HTML, and I want to make a professional header. My problem is that when I put my logo into my div and then put some links also in that div it splits them onto different lines. Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a table and put them in it:

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <th>
    <img src="https://smallbusinessbc.ca/wp-content/themes/sbbcmain/images/circle-icons/icon-education.svg" width="50px" height="50px">
  </th>
  <th>
    Write your stuff!
  </th>
</tr>
</table>
```

You can use any image and any text

Comment: @rahul-ahuja good to hear

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:flex` as shown below:

```css
.nav{
  border:1px solid black;
  display:flex;
}
.links{
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
  <div class="links">About Us | Contact Us</div>
</div>
```

Comment: does this work if "LOGO" is an image?